# Libmbed.a needed by '.../freedomboard_servo.elf'

Tags: matlab, mbed

I was going through the example of FRDM-KL25Z library in MATLAB Simulink and having some problems when deploying it to the board.

1) Most of the H files are missing in the directory during (compiling?) and was FIXED by downloading individually from website.

2) After the H files are fixed, MATLAB prompt me another error stating FILE_DIR/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libmbed.a' needed by ".../freedom_board_servo.elf'

I'm quite new to this field so was hoping someone can guide me through these errors as I have been stuck here doing nothing for few days fixing errors and errors.
Thanks.[libmbed.a ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIEj9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi all the problem is fixed by changing the directory of the file.
During installation MATLAB have named the directory wrongly "8e73be2a2ac1" was supposed to be named to "mbed-8e73be2a2ac1".